# How can I create own object / type in R?

Tags: r, oop

For example, I see the XTS object created using a package of same name. If I wanted to create for example a class of "Interest Rate Swap", would that be possible? How? I found an example using lambd.r here http://www.r-bloggers.com/pricing-interest-rate-swaps-with-lambda-r/ however that seems having to leverage functional programming. I searched for "constructor" in the R-Book, but nothing there.

Comment: see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `setClass` method. It, and the parameters, are described pretty well here:

[Site to Create an Object Class](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/setClass.html)

It allows you to set all of the parameters you would want to use to define a class and create objects for a package (like a SpatialPolygon from Leaflet). You can start with the basics found there, but you will likely want to read one of the books on creating packages if you intend to create a series of intertwined methods to work on a specific class of object you create.

Comment: just to be clear here, there is no class called "spatialPolygon", not in **leaflet** at least. There is however, a class called ["SpatialPolygons"](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/sp/html/SpatialPolygons-class.html) in the **sp** package. If you're delving into class creation and object oriented programming, concision is key! As for the question, have a good read through the OO-essentials linked above. You will have to make a decision which of the three OO-classes that R offers works best for your situation. They are very different and your decision will have huge implications...

Comment: Yeah...I rely on auto-complete for spelling. My apologies on that one! Thanks for catching me. I should have looked it up!